# Updating Repository and Error with installation of 3G Modem

Tags: repository, usb-modem, 3g

I have been facing issues while trying install iBall 21.0MP-58 dongle 3G. 
When I contacted the customer care, they initially said this is not compatible for Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. Later, they called to say that it is compatible, and tried to help. However, while trying to run sudp apt-get install I was facing error. So I sent them the screengrab of it. They looked at and said *"Attached images shows that, OS does not have the proper system repository for update packages. Any modem package will not get install until the repository is updated successfully."*

So I went ahead and updated the repository, based on some help in Ubuntu forum. That screenshot is attached. This is what I see when I run sudo apt update.

Do you think my repository is now updated? Please help because I have a feeling iBall is playing ball with me. I want to be sure if they are pinning the right issue here. I am new to Ubuntu and a complete non-techie person. But I can follow your instructions to the tee. 
[here is the screengrab of what i see after repository update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iqTu8.png)

Comment: The only issue I see here is that of `skype` else all is well at least from what I see.